# Checkout branch in Git Extensions creates branch with uppercase name

Tags: git, github, git-extensions

When I check out a branch by right-clicking on the branch and choosing "Checkout Branch | origin/f/xxxx",  I see the following dialog box.  After pressing checkout,  it seems that the local branch is named with an uppercase letter.  (See highlight)  When I push to the remote (on GitHub),  I am asked to create a new tracking reference on the server and a new branch is created because it is case sensitive.   The UI doesn't allow me to push to "f/xxxx" or rename the branch.

I've checked my ignore case setting:

> $ git config --get core.ignorecase
>
> true

Any idea why this happens?

Thanks

Comment: I'm having a similar problem. I create a branch named feature/feature_one, and it ends up being FEATURE/feature_one. Please any help?

Answer (score 1):

In my .git\refs\heads\ folder,  the "f" directory was uppercased.  Not sure which software was to blame for creating it that way - GitExtensions, SourceTree, or the GitHub.com windows desktop client.   By renaming it to lowercase,  I no longer had the problem.

Comment: It might be related to Windows insensitivity to char cases.